# How to link 4 points in each group in order to visualize the "moving direction"?

Tags: r, plot

I have a matrix `data` resulted from PCA. Each row contains a pair of coordinates. Moreover, I have a vector `row_name` that contains the name of each row. In particular, `row_name` is

```
   PAYS
1    AL
2    AL
3    AL
4    AL
5    AU
6    AU
7    AU
8    AU
9    BE
...
```

, i.e.,  the initials of the country. Each name appears 4 times, corresponding to 4 years 1975, 1977, 1979 and 1981.

I would like to ask how to highlight the groups of 4 points related to each country and link them in order to visualize the "moving direction" of each country. Thank you so much for your help!

```
OECD <- read.table("http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~xgendre/ens/data/OCDE", col.names=c("PAYS", "NATA", "CHOM", "APRI", "ASEC", "PIB", "FBCF", "INFL", "RECC", "MINF", "PROT", "NRJ"))

ACP <- prcomp(OECD[-1],
              retx = TRUE,
              scale = TRUE)

data <- (ACP$x)[, 1:2]
row_name <- OECD[1]

plot(data,  pch = 2, col = "orange")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add arrows to your plot using the `arrows` function. I made each country group a different color to make it slightly clearer which points are in which group.

```
plot(data,  pch = 2, col = rep(rainbow(nrow(data)/4), each=4))
for(i in seq(0,nrow(data)-4, 4)) {
    arrows(data[(1:3)+i,1], data[(1:3)+i,2], 
        data[(2:4)+i,1], data[(2:4)+i,2],
        length=0.1) }
```

[image: Same country connected by arrows]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wants.